# Finding Product Purchase Interval

Tags: java, mysql, database, model

Its about Finding Product Purchase Interval

**Problem Statement:**

You are given with following data:

- List of Products
- List of Customers
- List of Orders (Assume each order
  contains one product only)

**To Find:**

For each product and customer, find the average gap between consecutive product purchases and the average across all customers.

**Expected Output:**

Data model for input data and output results.
Display the output on screen as follows:

```
+----------------+-----------+------------+
|  SN |Product   | Customer  | AvgGap(days)
+-----------------------------------------+
|  1  | iPhone   | Snehal    | 21         |
|  *  |   ***    |  ***      | *          |
|     |          |           |            |
+-----+----------+-----------+------------+
```

---

**My Approach:**

1. Create an API to collect the data from the user about list of customers, products and all the orders placed to store into DB.
2. Store it in DB using following structure something like below (Since we want output to be product driven):

   ```
      +-------------+         +----------+        +--------------+
      | Product      <----->  |  Order   | <----> |  Customer    |
      +-------------+         +----------+        +--------------+

       product_id               order_id             customer_id
       product_name             product_id           customer_name
       price                    customer_id          address
       etc                      date_of_order        etc
   ```
3. To display output, create a map as `< Product, List<Customer>>` `productAndCustomers`, iterating which would give the results.
4. Iterate through list of orders (fetched from DB) to populate the map - `productAndCustomers`

---

For each order -

a. Get the product details and refer it with `product`

b. Get the customer details and refer it with `customer`

c. Add this customer to `List<Customer>` customers and check if this exists in the `productAndCustomers` map for the given `product` (key).

1. If exists, meaning customer has already ordered the product before. Update the `gap` attribute in customer [* How do I calculate the `gap` value? *]
2. If doesn’t exist, it means customer has never ordered this product. Create new `list <Customer> customers` and add this customer to list and put the [key, value] combination to map `productAndCustomers`.
   d. If It doesn’ t, it means the given product itself is not present in the map `productAndCustomers`. Put the key `product` and value `customers` list to this map with updated `gap` value.

So how do I calcualte the avg gap value? Should I maintain a list of `pastOrderDates` in `orders` to calculate it? But again how do I have that since gap is specific to `product` and `customer` combination. e.g. Snehal ordered iPhone on 5th and then ordered same again on 15th. Here gap being 10 days for specific combination. So before adding order entry to DB, do I need to check the combination and then update the `pastOrderDates`?

Comment: You would typically have a table of orders (order_id,order_date,customer) and a table of order_details (order_id,product_id)

Answer (score 1):

The only intricacy here is calculating the avg gaps between the purchases. This can be dealt while inserting the data to DB by maintaining the past order dates if the order has combination of same customer and product.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do seems very inconvenient to me.
A database is partly there so you don't have to have local lists of everything.

First of all, infos on how to **calculate the gap** a.k.a. the time difference can be found here [Calculating the difference between two Java date instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances).

On how to to **find a solution to you problem**, I'm only giving a basic outline here:

1. Join the three tables using the `customer_ID` and `product_ID`, group them by `customer_ID` and then by `product_ID`.
2. Take all groups with 2 or more elements and calculate the gaps between the purchases and save them accordingly.
3. Calculate the average for each product.